# Keep the permissions even when device is switched off

Tags: android, android-permissions

My device is such that my android app is always connected to an Arduino board through a USB. On device reboot my Android app forgets the USB permissions granted using intent filter in the manifest. I want my app to remember permissions for communicating with the Arduino board across power on/off cycles (Something that it is currently not doing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out that there isn't a way to go about it yet. So thank you for your time.